# webRTC on iOS: Can't send SDP answer, RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription() failed

Tags: ios, webrtc, sdp, libjingle

I'm using `libjingle_peerconnection` installed with cocoapods. When I receive SDP offer through signaling server from my caller, I'm trying to set this as a remote description, which triggers `RTCSessionDescriptionDelegate` `peerConnection:didSetSessionDescriptionWithError:`
with error:

`Error Domain=RTCSDPError Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={error=Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INIT}`.

My code is:

```
- (void)transportChanell:(TransportChannel *)channel didReceivedSignalWithSessionDescription:(NSString *)sessionDescription withType:(NSString *)type {
    RTCSessionDescription *remoteDesc = [[RTCSessionDescription alloc] initWithType:@"answer" sdp:sessionDescription];
    [_peerConnection setRemoteDescriptionWithDelegate:self sessionDescription:remoteDesc];
}
```

I've investigated the problem quite a lot and found in webRTC source code the place, as I suppose, this error comes from `BadRemoteSdp(type, BadStateErrMsg(state()), err_desc);` and all possible states of `WebRtcSession` are:

```
    STATE_INIT = 0,
    STATE_SENTOFFER,         // Sent offer, waiting for answer.
    STATE_RECEIVEDOFFER,     // Received an offer. Need to send answer.
    STATE_SENTPRANSWER,      // Sent provisional answer. Need to send answer.
    STATE_RECEIVEDPRANSWER,  // Received provisional answer, waiting for answer.
    STATE_INPROGRESS,        // Offer/answer exchange completed.
    STATE_CLOSED,            // Close() was called.
```

Any suggestions, please, what could I missed in caller or callee side?

Answer (score 2):

The offer seems to be marked as an "answer" according to the error message. It fails because it then expects you to be in the STATE_SENTOFFER state.

If you have created an offer and sent it to the other party, you may have forgotten to call setLocalDescription first. If you did not send an offer from the failing client, the other party should be changed to send an offer instead of an answer.

Comment: I hope I described all clearly: the problem is on callee side when I received the offer from caller. What should I do if I only to want see caller's stream on callee side and not to stream callee back to caller? Should callee create offer too or I should only send an answer to the already received offer (that's what I'm trying now).

Comment: If I would have forgotten to call `setLocalDescription` — I couldn't get SDP offer to send it through signaling server, which I did successfully. But as I already said, I generate offer only on the caller side, and want to get answer from callee, which is failed. Am I doing that thing wrong and callee side should genereate offer first too?

Answer (score 0):

In the event this helps anyone coming here from Google:

I ran into this problem myself, and it turned out I'd hastily copy-pasted some code from the offerer I'd written. So I was init'ing `RTCSessionDescription` with type `RTCSdpTypeAnswer` instead of `RTCSdpTypeOffer`.

Make sure when allocating your `RTCSessionDescription` that you're using the right type!